# Using structural commands in \newcommand - structure messed up?

Tags: macros, sectioning, texmaker

Is it right that usage of structural commands like `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection` and the like inside of `\newcommand` screws up the document's structure? I've got a `\section*{...}` inside a `\newcommand` block and using that new command does not work properly.

In Texmaker when I use the structure view to navigate through the document, clicking on the corresponding node in the tree moves the focus to the one `\section` command inside the `\newcommand` block instead of the ones that should actually be generated by usage of the custom command in different spots of the document. Complicating, I know.

I hope you'll get the point. What do I have to do to get custom commands to produce a correct document structure?

//edit: Here's an example of my problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\newcommand{\sectionexample}[2]{
    \section*{#1}
    This is an Example of what I think is not working...
    #2
}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \sectionexample{Test}{Hello World!}
\end{document}
```

This generates correct output aside from the fact that the section headline is missing in the \tableofcontents.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Texmaker uses the sectional commands in order to build a structure tree of the document. But this has nothing to do with the way LaTeX works; it's only a commodity that some find useful (I don't, for instance).

Comment: Are you saying that your output is incorrect, or that `TexMaker` can not properly navigate it? If it is the latter I think my comments starting at [Displaying current chapter/section in your editor](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83013/displaying-current-chapter-section-in-your-editor#comment177947_83013), and the follow on comments would explain what is going on.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: My output is incorrect as well. The \tableofcontents remains empty. Everything else is working like a charm. Or lets say at least what I'm doing with the structural information is working. I don't know about other features I haven't been using, yet.

Comment: I think the issue is that you are using `section*` which not only suppresses the section number but also does not add it to the TOC.  You need to do a `\phantomsection` (needed for `hyperref`) and `\addcontentsline` with `\section*` to get the unnumbered section in the TOC.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is that a general fact? Actually, I think, I've seen section* headlines in a TOC before... may be another document class? Or does that apply to all document classes?

Comment: Related: [No section numbers, but still have PDF bookmarks with hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33696/17427); some of the answers there provide solutions for getting unnumbered sections into the table of contents, independently of `hyperref` and PDF bookmarks.

Answer (score 3):

Some classes don't distinguish between `\section` and `\section*` as far as insertion in the table of contents is concerned. For instance the AMS classes behave in this way.

The standard LaTeX classes and the KoMa-Script classes, instead, do not automatically insert starred sectional commands in the table of contents.

If you use one of the standard classes, for instance `report`, or a class based on them, you have to "manually" do the insertion. For `report` it should be

```
\providecommand{\phantomsection}{}
\newcommand{\sectionexample}[2]{%
    \section*{#1}
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
    This is an Example of what I think is not working...
    #2
}
```

The `\phantomsection` bit is needed in case you plan to use `hyperref`.

With the `scrreprt` class you can do

```
\newcommand{\sectionexample}[2]{%
    \addsec{#1}
    This is an Example of what I think is not working...
    #2
}
```

that doesn't require tricks in case `hyperref` is loaded.

Note that this will probably fool Texmaker's ability of showing a correct structure tree for the document. But this isn't related to LaTeX.

Comment: Alright, guess it's rather a Texmaker issue that made me ask. Thanks anyway!